# Defining a command for linked and indexed section headings?

Tags: cross-referencing, macros, links

What is the (preferred way of) defining a command that

- places a heading (like \section, \chapter, etc.)
- creates a label for this heading that can be referenced
- places the heading in the TOC (I think the TOC part is pretty automatic, yes?)
- places the heading in the index

and what is the (preferred way of) defining a referencing command that

- places a reference to the heading with the name of the heading and it's page number
- makes this reference a Link when generating a PDF
- maybe some options on how the referencing should be spelled out

and what packages are needed for this?

Example:

```
\headx[label1]{This is a heading}
...
\headxx[label12}]{Some sub-heading}
...
...
For further details, see \headreference[style=short]{label1}.
...
```

(edit) Note: `[style=...]` could control what details are inserted. E.g. `short` could mean to only insert the section name as link (and skip the section number and page). `Full`could mean to also insert section number and page as text for the link. (This is just an example to show that I think that such a command should probably have some fine-tuning switches.)

Comment: What is the `[style=short]` supposed to do?

Answer (score 3):

The [hyperref](http://ctan.org/pkg/) package can help you to do pretty much all what you're asking for. Have a look at it's documentation (e.g. by running `texdoc hyperref` on a command line) and have a close look at the section on “Additional user macros”. Here are some macro definitions to get you started:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\mychapter}[2][???]{\chapter{#2}\label{#1}}
\newcommand{\verylongref}[1]{%
  \hyperref[#1]{\autoref*{#1} with title `\nameref*{#1}' in page \pageref*{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

\mychapter[hello]{Hello World}

This is \verylongref{hello}.

\end{document}
```

Note that the `\mychapter` command has the interface you we're looking for, but it has two problems: the “optional” argument is not really optional since (of course) you *do* need a label to assign to the chapter; and, moreover, `\chapter` already had an optional argument (which is used as a short title for running headers) and now it's no longer accessible with the `\mychapter` command. Maybe it's better just to keep writing `\chapter{..}\label{..}`?