# Linking the section titles to the ToC

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, links

(Somewhat related to [Defining a Command for Linked and Indexed Section Headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3312/defining-a-command-for-linked-and-indexed-section-headings)).

I'm trying to have the section headings link to their entry in the Table of Contents so as to get "two-way" navigation, eg: a user looks in the Table of Contents for a section title, jumps there, reads a couple of lines, clicks on the section title again and gets taken to the section's entry in the Table of Contents once more.

My original question is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32495/linking-the-section-text-to-the-toc), from the discussion there I got the following code:

```
\newcounter{tocBackrefCount}
\newcommand{\Chapter}[3]{%
\chapter%
(#1)%
[\protect\raisebox{\baselineskip}{\protect\hypertarget{toc:backref:\thetocBackrefCount}{}}#2]%
{\hyperlink{toc:backref:\thetocBackrefCount}{#3}}\stepcounter{tocBackrefCount}%
}
```

(nb: the parenthesis argument for `\chapter` are a courtesy of the [`hypbmsec` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hypbmsec)) this macro is called like so `\Chapter{bookmark}{short}{long}`, where `bookmark` is the bookmark name as you wish it to appear in the viewer, `short` is the ToC entry, and `long` is the actual section title (in text, the one which will be linked).

I currently face three problems with this approach:

1. It takes between 3 to 5 compilation runs to get all the references in place (maybe the [hypdestopt package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hypdestopt) has something to do with it...?).
2. It's **ugly**, I'd much rather have a redefinition of the standard `\chapter` and `\chapter*` commands, or at least make it take optional arguments which default like the standard ones.

Care to share your TeXpertise on the matter?

PS: the `\raisebox` command is there to avoid `hyperref` setting the target's anchor to the lower-left corner of the ToC entry (try it without it and you'll see what I mean).

PPS: here's a MWE for your viewing pleasure:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linktocpage]{hyperref}
\usepackage{hypbmsec}
\newcounter{tocBackrefCount}
\newcommand{\Chapter}[3]{%
\chapter(#1)%
[\protect\raisebox{\baselineskip}{\protect\hypertarget{toc:backref:\thetocBackrefCount}{}}#2]%
{\hyperlink{toc:backref:\thetocBackrefCount}{#3}}%
\stepcounter{tocBackrefCount}}
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \Chapter{Bookmark 1}{Short 1}{Long 1}
    \noindent\ldots
  \Chapter{Bookmark 2}{Short 2}{Long 2}
    \noindent\ldots
  \Chapter{Bookmark 3}{Short 3}{Long 3}
    \noindent\ldots
  \Chapter{Bookmark 4}{Short 4}{Long 4}
    \noindent\ldots
  \Chapter{Bookmark 5}{Short 5}{Long 5}
    \noindent\ldots
  \Chapter{Bookmark 6}{Short 6}{Long 6}
    \noindent\ldots
  \Chapter{Bookmark 7}{Short 7}{Long 7}
    \noindent\ldots
\end{document}
```

## Possible ***Nice*** Solution

Fiddling around with this for the best part of the weekend I got the following "final" version of @egreg's code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linktocpage,plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{hypbmsec}
\usepackage{hypdestopt}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{tocBackrefCount}

\def\MPR@command#1{%
  \AtBeginDocument{\csletcs{HYPBMSEC@#1}{#1}\csletcs{#1}{MPR@#1}}%
  \expandafter\DeclareDocumentCommand\csname MPR@#1\endcsname{s d() o m}{
    \stepcounter{tocBackrefCount}
    \IfBooleanTF{##1}
      {\IfNoValueTF{##2}
        {\IfNoValueTF{##3}
          {\addtocounter{tocBackrefCount}{-1}\@nameuse{HYPBMSEC@#1}*{##4}}
          {\@nameuse{HYPBMSEC@#1}*{\phantomsection{}\mpr@mand{##4}%
            \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{\texorpdfstring{\mpr@opt{##3}}{##3}}}}
        }
        {\IfNoValueTF{##3}
          {\@nameuse{HYPBMSEC@#1}*{\phantomsection{}\mpr@mand{##4}%
            \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{\texorpdfstring{\mpr@opt{##4}}{##2}}}}
          {\@nameuse{HYPBMSEC@#1}*{\phantomsection{}\mpr@mand{##4}%
            \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{\texorpdfstring{\mpr@opt{##3}}{##2}}}}
        }
      }
      {\IfNoValueTF{##2}
        {\IfNoValueTF{##3}
          {\@nameuse{HYPBMSEC@#1}(##4)[\mpr@opt{##4}]{\mpr@mand{##4}}}
          {\@nameuse{HYPBMSEC@#1}(##3)[\mpr@opt{##3}]{\mpr@mand{##4}}}
        }
        {\IfNoValueTF{##3}
          {\@nameuse{HYPBMSEC@#1}(##2)[\mpr@opt{##4}]{\mpr@mand{##4}}}
          {\@nameuse{HYPBMSEC@#1}(##2)[\mpr@opt{##3}]{\mpr@mand{##4}}}
        }
      }
  }
}
\def\mpr@opt#1{\protect\raisebox{1.6ex}{%
  \protect\hypertarget{toc:backref:\thetocBackrefCount}{}}#1}
\def\mpr@mand#1{\hyperlink{toc:backref:\thetocBackrefCount}{#1}}

\MPR@command{chapter}
\MPR@command{section}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \chapter{No optional argument}
    \noindent\ldots

  \section{ABC}
    \noindent\ldots

  \chapter[opt]{Optional argument}
    \noindent\ldots

  \chapter(book){No optional argument + bookmark}
    \noindent\ldots

  \chapter(book)[opt]{Both optional arguments}
    \noindent\ldots

  \chapter*{No optional argument}
    \noindent\ldots

  \section*{ABC}
    \noindent\ldots

  \chapter*[opt]{Optional argument}
    \noindent\ldots

  \chapter*(book){No optional argument + bookmark}
    \noindent\ldots

  \chapter*(book)[opt]{Both optional arguments}
    \noindent\ldots

\end{document}
```

This deals gracefully with starred versions of the sectioning commands. Note the addition of the [`hypdestopt` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hypdestopt): without it you'd get spurious warnings about duplicated `hyperref` targets.

Note that we no longer `\reisebox` by a whole `\bsaelineskip`: that produces certain undesired artifacts in the ToC; instead, the empirically sound value of `1.6ex` is used. I wager this will *not* be a sure shot solution and am open to suggestions on this matter.

This solution works the best for me, but I'd like to hear your ideas as well, I'm sure there's more to be said on the matter!

Comment: Do you think you could turn your code into a complete MWE? It really helps people recreate the problem you're describing!

Comment: This is actually a _very_ good exercise: whilst trying to make the MWE compile I found out a dependency on fixltx2e I totally missed (it's one of the packages on my "always include" list).

Comment: The dependency on **fixltx2e** can be eliminated by using `\protect\raisebox`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linktocpage]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{hypbmsec}

\newcounter{tocBackrefCount}

\makeatletter
\def\MPR@chapter{\@ifstar{\HYPBMSEC@chapter*}\MPR@chapter@}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\MPR@chapter@}{d() o m}{
  \stepcounter{tocBackrefCount}
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
      {\HYPBMSEC@chapter(#3)[\mpr@opt{#3}]{\mpr@mand{#3}}}
      {\HYPBMSEC@chapter(#2)[\mpr@opt{#2}]{\mpr@mand{#3}}}
    }
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
      {\HYPBMSEC@chapter(#1)[\mpr@opt{#3}]{\mpr@mand{#3}}}
      {\HYPBMSEC@chapter(#1)[\mpr@opt{#2}]{\mpr@mand{#3}}}
    }
}
\def\mpr@opt#1{\protect\raisebox{\baselineskip}{%
  \protect\hypertarget{toc:backref:\thetocBackrefCount}{}}#1}
\def\mpr@mand#1{\hyperlink{toc:backref:\thetocBackrefCount}{#1}}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \let\HYPBMSEC@chapter\chapter
  \let\chapter\MPR@chapter
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \chapter{No optional argument}
    \noindent\ldots
  \chapter[opt]{Optional argument}
    \noindent\ldots
  \chapter(book){No optional argument + bookmark}
    \noindent\ldots
  \chapter(book)[opt]{Both optional arguments}
    \noindent\ldots
\end{document}
```

Loading **bookmark** usually saves the number of LaTeX runs.

### Generic definitions

Here is how one can extend the previous method to redefine all desired sectional commands

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xparse,etoolbox}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linktocpage]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{hypbmsec}

\makeatletter

\newcounter{tocBackrefCount}

\def\MPR@command#1{%
  \AtBeginDocument{\csletcs{HYPBMSEC@#1}{#1}\csletcs{#1}{MPR@#1}}%
  \@namedef{MPR@#1}{\@ifstar{\@nameuse{HYPBMSEC@#1}*}{\@nameuse{MPR@#1@}}}%
  % define \MPR@<command>@
  \expandafter\DeclareDocumentCommand\csname MPR@#1@\endcsname{d() o m}{
    \stepcounter{tocBackrefCount}
    \IfNoValueTF{##1}
      {\IfNoValueTF{##2}
        {\@nameuse{HYPBMSEC@#1}(##3)[\mpr@opt{##3}]{\mpr@mand{##3}}}
        {\@nameuse{HYPBMSEC@#1}(##2)[\mpr@opt{##2}]{\mpr@mand{##3}}}
      }
      {\IfNoValueTF{##2}
        {\@nameuse{HYPBMSEC@#1}(##1)[\mpr@opt{##3}]{\mpr@mand{##3}}}
        {\@nameuse{HYPBMSEC@#1}(##1)[\mpr@opt{##2}]{\mpr@mand{##3}}}
      }
  }
}
\def\mpr@opt#1{\protect\raisebox{\baselineskip}{%
  \protect\hypertarget{toc:backref:\thetocBackrefCount}{}}#1}
\def\mpr@mand#1{\hyperlink{toc:backref:\thetocBackrefCount}{#1}}

\MPR@command{chapter}
\MPR@command{section}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{No optional argument}
\noindent\ldots
\section{ABC}
\noindent\ldots

\chapter[opt]{Optional argument}
\noindent\ldots

\chapter(book){No optional argument + bookmark}
\noindent\ldots

\chapter(book)[opt]{Both optional arguments}
\noindent\ldots

\end{document}
```

Now one has only to list what commands to redefine, in this example only `\chapter` and `\section`, via `\MPR@command{<section level>}`.

I've not succeeded in redefining conveniently `\chapter*` and similar to allow for optional arguments. Still thinking about it.

Comment: Sorry it took me this long to respond. Your MWE works like a charm btw. Two requests though. Firstly, I can't seem to get the code to generalize to sections, etc. all the way down to subparagraphs... would you care to provide further examples? Secondly, I usually use `\chapter*` followed by `\phantomsection` and `\addcontentsline` to get unnumbered sections which _do_ appear in the ToC (and should thus be linked), is there any way to modify your `\chapter*` definition above to achieve this? (and define, for instance, `\chapter**` to behave like a "normal" `\chapter*`)?

Comment: This is GREAT! Thanks a million! Please do let me know if you can come up with a solution for the starred commands. I (unelegantly) "solved" this issue by inserting `\addcontentsline` commands... don't know if it helps though. PS: I'll mark this question answered nevertheless, you've given me much code to ponder about :)

Comment: I think I managed to accomplish a "working" solution which is not excessively horrid, alas I can't post code snippets here (and I'm _not_ gonna make further noise by presenting my own, possibly wrong, answers as I've done this far)... anyway, I get lots of "innocent" `destination with the same identifier...` warnings... If you find a way I can post this piece of code without adding further confusion let me know please :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the usual pattern to wrap some command into another one. For the chapter example:

```
\let\chapterOriginal\chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}{...\chapterOriginal ...}
```

The "let" creates another name for the original command, which is still valid, when the original command is redefined.

Comment: I thought about that, then I read [this entry on the TeX UK FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=patch) and got squeamish... is it safe to use the `\let` method for `\chapter`? (seeing as it takes optional arguments)